# Adding background to div using props

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a slider and adding data to it using prop. Each slide div has a heading and a description. I also want to give a different image background to each div. Is it possible to add a background image to the divs using props?

Here's my approach to it but it's not working:

```
const slideData = [
    {
        id: 1,
        heading: "First Heading",
        description: "A short description of the service goes here",
        image: './images/candle.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        heading: "Second Heading",
        description: "A short description of the service goes here",
        image: './images/candle.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        heading: "Third Heading",
        description: "A short description of the service goes here",
        image: './images/candle.jpg'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        heading: "Fourth Heading",
        description: "A short description of the service goes here",
        image: './images/candle.jpg'
    }
]

export default slideData
```

And child component

```
import React from 'react';

function Slide(props) {
    return (
        <div className="slide" style={{background: props.image}}>
            <h3> { props.heading} </h3>
            <p> { props.description} </p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Slide;
```

Comment: Have you checked if path to background image is OK?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can you're actually looking for the `backgroundImage` attribute. And to use it with `props`, you need to use `string-interpolation`.

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/solitary-lake-fey03

```
function Slide(props) {
  return (
    <div className="slide" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.image})` }}>
      <h3> {props.heading} </h3>
      <p> {props.description} </p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Slide;
```

Comment: @TalhaMunir I've added some cat pics and the actual slider functionality if you need a reference :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this code snippet will help you

```
style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${props.image})`
```